# Пунктуация вопроса "знаешь что?"

Tags: пунктуация, спп, придаточное-предложение

Как написать правильно: *знаешь что* или же *знаешь, что*? Читала, что если придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения состоит из одного слова, то запятая не ставится, значит ли это, что правильный вариант — "знаешь что"?

Answer (score 4):

Ответ изменён.

Итак, задано выражение "знаешь что". Требуется определить, в каких случаях запятая не ставится, то есть когда это выражение является **цельным по смыслу** (пусть  не точно по Розенталю, но с тем же **определением**).

Если это цельное выражение (без запятой), то "знаешь" по смыслу близко к указательной частице "вот", то есть выражение  "знаешь что" можно заменить выражением "вот что". А теперь посмотрим, в каких синтаксических конструкциях это выражение встречается.

**Вариант 1. "Знаешь что" в предложении с инверсией:**

Сравнить:

(1) **Знаешь, что** бы сделал я на твоём месте? [Владимир Войнович. Иванькиада, или рассказ о вселении писателя Войновича в новую квартиру (1976)]

(2) ― А я бы на твоём месте **знаешь что** сделал? [Владимир Войнович. Иванькиада, или рассказ о вселении писателя Войновича в новую квартиру (1976)]

**Вариант 2. В качестве самостоятельного выражения со значением "вот что я скажу"**

Он сказал: ― **Знаешь что?** Ты лучше меня жалей. [Юрий Трифонов. Дом на набережной (1976)]

― **Знаешь что**, ― сказал я, тщательно облизывая ложку, ― я передумал. [В. Т. Шаламов. Колымские рассказы (1954-1961)]

Comment: Розенталь пишет, что цельные по смыслу выражения не выделяются знаками препинания. Пример (2) подходит. Но в других примерах - не тот тип выражения, и запятая стоит после "знаешь что": **А знаешь что, зайдём к нему сейчас, он тут за парком.** [Ю. О. Домбровский. Хранитель древностей / Приложение (1964)] . По-моему, это вводные слова в данном случае.

Comment: Я не согласна, Сибилла. В предложении "Ты ЧТО ХОЧЕШЬ думай" ЧТО ХОЧЕШЬ действительно является цельным по смыслу выражением. Но это абсолютно другой случай.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы, Сибилла. Действительно "знаешь что" можно заменить выражением "вот что", близким по значению к указательной частице.Удачные примеры из  Ю.Трифонова и В.Шаламова. Вот это я и хотела услышать.

Answer (score 1):

> Как написать правильно: "знаешь что?" или же "знаешь, что?"? Читала,
>   что если придаточная часть состоит сложноподчиненного предложения
>   состоит из одного слова, то запятая не ставится, значит ли это, что
>   правильный вариант - "знаешь что?"?

Если придаточное предложение в СПП состоит из одного союзного слова, то запятая перед ним НЕ ставится. Так звучит правило. Поэтому важно выяснить контекст предложений, в которых будет использоваться "ЗНАЕШЬ ЧТО".

Если это предложение следующего типа: *Ты прекрасно знаешь, что этого не следует делать*. Здесь  запятая ставится, так как придаточное изъяснительное распространено.

Если это предложение с придаточным, состоящим из одного союзного слова, то запятая не нужна. Например, *Я принесу тебе это завтра, и ты знаешь ЧТО.*

Если же придаточное в СПП содержит, кроме союзного слова, частицу, запятая ставится факультативно (на усмотрение автора). Например, *Я принесу тебе это завтра, и ты знаешь (,) ЧТО ИМЕННО.*

Подробнее, Ксения, можете прочитать на ГРАМОТА.РУ

Comment: Спасибо. Я имела в виду именно вопрос, ну, знаете, когда просто спрашиваешь кого-нибудь : "Знаешь(,) что?". Именно постановка запятой в вопросе вызывает затруднения

Comment: Спасибо, что уточнила, Ксения. Я думаю, здесь работает то же правило. И запятая перед ЧТО не нужна.

Comment: Наконец-то все прояснилось, огромное вам спасибо

Comment: @Ксения если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его галочкой слева.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, в этом случае "знаешь что" являются вводными словами, наподобие "знаешь ли". Вот примеры из Национального корпуса русского языка.

**Знаешь ли, дорогая Маруся, из-за этой чёртовой фанеры ничего не разобрать.** [Александр Дорофеев. Эле-Фантик // «Мурзилка», 2003]

**Знаешь что, Володя, ― сказала она, обращаясь к отцу, ― в конце концов, если ты так боишься, то лучше не ходи** [Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000)]

По-моему, как отдельное восклицание (неполное предложение) эти слова тоже надо писать без запятой.

**Знаешь что?**

Comment: У меня была мысль, что оборот "знаешь что" может терять в этом случае  своё прямое лексическое значение. Но, мне кажется, что он не равен вводному "знаешь ли", который используется для "привлечения внимания" (кажется так этот разряд называется?)

Comment: По-моему именно так, для привлечения внимания. В таком предложении, как **А знаешь что, зайдём к нему сейчас, он тут за парком.** Какая альтернатива? Придаточное?

Comment: Вообще-то к придаточному ставится вопрос. Здесь я этого сделать не могу. Может быть, вставная или вводная конструкция?