# Особенности употребления глагола "знаешь"

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, выбор-слов, глаголы

> Я еще(,) знаешь, что слышал...

В устной речи можно встретить такое выражение, которое кажется вполне понятным. Тем не менее то, как расставлять знаки пунктуации, ясно не до конца: первая часть произносится без пауз на одном дыхании, но синтаксичеси глагол *знаешь* относится к другой грамматической основе. Таким образом, постановка запятой затруднена.

Какое решение стоит признать наиболее подходящим?

Понятно, что, правив предложение, можно избежать особых трудностей, но вопрос не об этом.

Comment: Здесь было [что-то похожее](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429928/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE).

Comment: @grizzly спасибо. Там про другое :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В словаре "Трудности русской пунктуации" O.A. Остроумовой и О.Д. Фрамполь множество статей посвящено выражению со словами **знаешь, знаете**. К нашей ситуации относится только следующая статья (точнее, её часть).

> **ЗНАЕТЕ, ЗНАЕШЬ** частица, разг.
>
> 1. Невводное, употребляется в функции усилительной частицы внутри восклицательных и вопросительных предложений перед вопросительными
>      местоимениями, не обособляется: *Я имею знаешь какие предложения!*
>      (В.Панова); *Из-за них у отца знаешь какие неприятности?*
>      (Ф.Искандер); *А русский язык и литературу знаете как знает?*
>      (В.Железников).
>
> Тем не менее в художественных текстах нередко встречаются случаи
>   обособления данных слов в функции частицы: *То время, знаете, какое
>   было, идешь в рейс, а тебе дают в паек дюжину пуговиц и коробку синьки
>   — вот и вертись!* (К.Паустовский); *А тут, знаешь, народ какой?*
>   (М.Шолохов). Эти случаи обособления следует считать ошибочными.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы не стала ставить запятую: **Я еще знаешь что слышал...**

Сравнить: Я ещё **вот что слышал**.

Частица ***знаешь***  по смыслу соответствует частице ***вот***. Сравнить: *я знаешь что думаю (= я вот что думаю).*

Выражения ***знаешь как, знаешь что, знаешь где*** используется в утвердительных и вопросительных предложениях: Я знаешь что слышал...  Я знаешь что слышал?

Это не вводное слово ***знаешь***, которое обособляется и используется для привлечения внимания собеседника. И это не сказуемое в предложении: Знаешь, что я слышал? Фактически это то же предложение, но **с инверсией и необязательным вопросом.**

Таким образом,  мы имеем **устойчивую конструкцию частица + вопросительное местоимение.**

**Примеры:**

А потом, оно ж **знаешь как бывает**. [Владимир Войнович. Жизнь и необычайные приключения солдата Ивана Чонкина (1969-1975)]

Я и платье новое закажу. **Я знаешь что думаю?** Сделать себе убор из незабудок. [А. Н. Островский. Последняя жертва (1877)]

— Настя присела на стул, сдвинула на затылок белый пушистый платок. — Я **знаешь где** была? В навинах. [Федор Абрамов. Братья и сестры (1958)]

Comment: Приём с подстановкой "вот" не подходит для вопросительных предложений.

Comment: Подстановка - это всего лишь прием, который помогает определить  значение и функцию слова.

Answer (score 1):

В  Словаре-справочнике по пунктуации. — М.: Справочно-информационный интернет-портал ГРАМОТА.РУ. В. В. Свинцов, В. М. Пахомов, И. В. Филатова. 2010" то слово  относится к  вводному.

ЗНАЕТЕ / ЗНАЕШЬ (ЛИ), вводное слово

Служит для привлечения внимания собеседника или выражает сомнение, удивление, недоверие.
Иногда, **знаешь ли,** целый день барка за баркой подходит к молу... В. Гаршин, Встреча. ...У нее с братом какой-то странный образ мыслей, рассуждают они как-то, **знаете ли,** странно, и характер очень бойкий. А. Чехов, Человек в футляре. Теперь я, **знаете,** понаторел и попривык, а бывало сначала, ей-богу, измучишься, такой скверный нрав. А. Герцен, Мимоездом.

> Но  в Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правке,  Розенталь Д. Э.,
>   М.: 1989., слово **знаешь** относится как вводному, так и близкой к **частице**.

Ср.: Он, знаешь, человек обязательный (вводное слово).— А нам за это знаешь что будет? (близко к частице);

См. также: Большой толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова.
Разг. **Знаешь; знаете, в зн. вводн.** сл. Употр. с целью обратить внимание собеседника на предмет разговора. **Я, знаешь, читал Дюма. Одичаешь, знаете, если жить взаперти.**